# Helpful flags do not appear on my flagging history

Tags: support, flag-history, helpful-flags

Good morning, since last June 24 marked flags not appears on my flagging history in Stack Overflow, and I  have flagged 15 or 20.

What could be the problem?

I can add flags without any mistake and when I access to the post I can see that the flag is set correctly.

### **My current flagging history is:**

[image]

**

### And right now i flagged a question:

**
[image]

Comment: On what site exactly?

Comment: Sorry I have not explained, that are happening in Stackoverflow

Comment: OK, can you please add a screenshot of your flagging history page?

Comment: Yes, I edit my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing flags and close votes. Those are two different things.

Your close votes are available in your profile page under "votes" tab:

> [image]

And in there you can filter only close votes:

> [image]

Worth to mention, that when a user gets the [Cast Close And Reopen Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privilege, any flag of type "Should be closed" or "Duplicate" is automatically converted into actual close vote of same type. Since you just recently reached 3K on Stack Overflow, that's probably the cause of your confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So when i flag a question to close for a reason is not adding helpful flags? How I can get helpful flags? I would get Marshall medal.

Comment: True. The goal of flagging a question to be closed is to actually have it closed, so when you have the power to cast real close votes it makes sense to turn a flag (which has no real impact) to close vote. You can also flag answers which are Very Low Quality, Not An Answer etc.

Comment: Or flag questions/answers as spam ... some people still vote to close instead of flagging as spam - even for the really obvious ones :/

Comment: @David true, but spam is really rare thing to catch so I didn't mention it.